# 500 Internal Server Error when LIST files in App Data Folder

Tags: google-drive-api

Since few hours method LIST doesn't work when LIST files in App Data Folder.
Response is 500 Internal Server Error.

I use below scope:
SCOPE_DRIVE_APPDATA = "drive.appdata";

When I use both scopes everything is fine:
SCOPE_DRIVE = "drive";
SCOPE_DRIVE_APPDATA = "drive.appdata";

But my Android apps have only DRIVE_APPDATA in code.

Please fix it ASAP. All my apps stopped working!

Comment: Are you still experience this issue? I've tried to reproduce it and I successfully get a 200 response when I only use the appdata scope. Can you show what your full query is?

Comment: Issue has been fixed after few hours after reporting here: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3880

Comment: It was simple list query: "'appfolder' in parents". But there is still problem with long queries. I reported issue with long queries here: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3866